# Array_Diff is deleting only the key/value from the array of objects but not the whole object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a script that ultimately produces a JSON array. Producing the JSON array works fine, with the exception that I can't seem to delete an entire object from an array of objects when searching for a specific keys value.

**Producing the Array:**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `emails` WHERE `subject` LIKE '%5678%' order by `id` DESC LIMIT 50";
$result = mysqli_query($DatabasePointer2,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($DatabasePointer2));
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if($row_cnt>0) {
    $array = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $i++;
        $a1 = explode('-', $row['body']);
        $a1[0] = str_replace("","",$a1[0]);
        $a1[1] = str_replace("TF: ","",$a1[1]);
        $a1[1] = str_replace("minutes","M",$a1[1]); 
        $a = array(
            "p" => "test", 
            "id" => $row['id'], 
            "thekey" => $a1[1], 
            "time" => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
            "utctime" => strtotime($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 
            "utc2" =>  $two->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
            "utc3" =>  $three->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
        $a1 = array_diff($a, ["keytoexclude1", "keytoexclude2", "keytoexclude3"]);

        $array[] = $a1;
    }       
}
echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Note that value of `thekey` is not static.

**The code above, produces this:**

```
[{
    "p": "test",
    "id": "198645",
    "time": "2020-05-06 23:00:49",
    "utctime": 1588806049,
    "utc2": "2020-05-07 01:00:49",
    "utc3": "2020-05-07 02:00:49"
}, {
    "p": "test",
    "id": "198605",
    "time": "2020-05-06 22:00:55",
    "utctime": 1588802455,
    "utc2": "2020-05-07 00:00:55",
    "utc3": "2020-05-07 01:00:55",
    "thekey": "123456"
}, {
    "p": "test",
    "id": "198604",
    "time": "2020-05-06 22:00:54",
    "utctime": 1588802454,
    "utc2": "2020-05-07 00:00:54",
    "utc3": "2020-05-07 01:00:54"
}]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to search for any key that matches a list of exclusions, and then remove the whole object if it finds a key in the list of exclusions.

**List of Exclusions/Code to remove...**

```
$a1 = array_diff($a, ["keytoexclude1", "keytoexclude2", "keytoexclude3"]);
```

Whats happening, is that it just removes the key/value itself, but keeps the rest of the object.
If you look in the array above, you'll see that if an exclusion was found, it only removes "thekey" and its value from the object, but leaves the rest of the keys in the objects.

Can somebody please assist in how to remove the whole object?

**Updated to show mistake where the value for "thekey" isn't supposed to come from the mysql database, but the exploded array.

Comment: `$a` is a one-dimensional associative array. But then you show a 2-dimensional array, where did that come from?

Comment: `array_diff()` works on values, not keys. And it doesn't look in nested arrays.

Comment: `array_diff_key()` compares keys, but both arrays have to be associative.

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're trying to exclude. But I suspect what you're looking for is `array_filter()`.

Comment: Let me add a little more code. $a is inside of a while loop after reading data from the mysql database.

Comment: Why does only the second element of the array have `thekey`?

Comment: Maybe you meant `$a[] = array(...)`?

Comment: Does this new update help a little more?

Comment: What is `$a1`, should that be `$a`?

Comment: Not much. Should the argument to `array_diff()` be `$a` or `$array`?

Comment: Just updated a piece of the code to show that $a1 is an exploded array, then variables are changed, and then $a is formed. As to your question about whether array diff should be to $a... I don't think so because its really just the php array that constructs the JSON array of objects, and that's really what needs to be filtered... or at least I thought so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213296/discussion-between-barmar-and-user3259138).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to check if the value is in the list of exclusions, and skip the row.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (in_array($row['thevalue'], ["keytoexclude1", "keytoexclude2", "keytoexclude3"])) {
            continue;
        }
        $a = array(
            "p" => "test", 
            "id" => $row['id'], 
            "thekey" => $row['thevalue'], 
            "time" => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
            "utctime" => strtotime($dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 
            "utc2" =>  $two->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
            "utc3" =>  $three->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
        $array[] = $a1;
    }
```